# How to add container without destroying table

Tags: html, css-tables

I created a table out of divs. The first column got the captions for the whole table. Because of having a lot of lines I wanted to list it in pages. So I put a container above every part I wanted as a page. Like this:

```
<div class="table">    
    <div class="tableRow">
        <div class="tableCell">1</div>
        <div class="tableCell">2</div>
        <div class="tableCell">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="page1">
        <div class="tableRow">
            <div class="tableCell">111111</div>
            <div class="tableCell">222222</div>
            <div class="tableCell">333333</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="page2">
        <div class="tableRow">
            <div class="tableCell">111111</div>
            <div class="tableCell">222222</div>
            <div class="tableCell">333333</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I use this as a table every page gets into the first row.

How could I let CSS ignore my pagecontainer?

I'm really sorry if this question has already been asked but I really don't know how to describe it better or what I have to look for.

Comment: Why do you need an extra container for that – especially with each container holding just _one_ row of data by the looks of it?

Comment: it is an example. every container contains 10 lines and i got up to 130 lines. I need this in this format because ob beeing able to sort them, editing, etc.

Comment: I don't follow. What do you do that puts every page into the first row? CSS? Javascript? What error or undesired output are you getting?

Comment: its a generated code out of my database. i get a dataTable in C# and have to gernerate in javascript a table to edit every single part of the data entry while using templates. this example shows how the table is generated. But in action this table is much more complicated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `display: table-row-group;` on your wrappers. This will make them behave like `tbody` elements (see the [docs](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)).

For example:

```css
.table {
    display: table;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
}
.tableRowGroup {
    display: table-row-group;
}
.tableRow {
    display: table-row;
}
.tableCell {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">    
    <div class="tableRow">
        <div class="tableCell">1</div>
        <div class="tableCell">2</div>
        <div class="tableCell">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="page1 tableRowGroup">
        <div class="tableRow">
            <div class="tableCell">111111</div>
            <div class="tableCell">222222</div>
            <div class="tableCell">333333</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="page2 tableRowGroup">
        <div class="tableRow">
            <div class="tableCell">111111</div>
            <div class="tableCell">222222</div>
            <div class="tableCell">333333</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[*Here a fiddle.*](http://jsfiddle.net/rmndfbet/)**